# Changing form input field types with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, types

I frequently find myself opening up Web Inspector in Safari when registering on a website and then changing the password field to a text field so I can view the text entered and don't have those black dots that cover up the password.

Opening Web Inspector time and time again is bit of a hassle so I wondered if it wouldn't be possible to use a piece of JS code in my bookmark bar and when I click it, the javascript changes every form input field with `type="password"` to `type="text"`

Tried some things I found on the web, but they didn't really work…

Comment: It's doable, and not really too complicated, but Stackoverflow isn't a "write your entire program for you" service. Break the task down into steps, have a go at implementing them, if you get stuck do a search for solving that particular problem, then ask a Stackoverflow question if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
document.querySelector("[type=password]").setAttribute("type","text");
```